# Azure DB Sequencial numbering

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I'm having a few issues with designing a database in Azure at the moment, down to the following:

1. SQL2012 Auto-Increment keys can/will jump by 1000 fairly regularly, related to the new "feature" of SQL 2012, as documented here [(link)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d256650-0e94-4d0f-8b52-0ba6e1903215/primary-key-auto-incrementing-by-1000-instead-of-1). This has been closed on "By Design" in Connect [(link)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)
2. The recommendation is to use either a startup flag to avoid this behaviour (cannot do with Azure), or to use Sequences to generate incrementing numbers instead.
3. However, SEQUENCE is unsupported in Azure DB. It in fact alternates between being an active issue and a "won't fix" issue on Connect [(link)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/723601/support-native-sequences-in-sql-azure)

So, my question is how to actually go about having a field auto-increment by 1 on insert to an Azure DB table, whilst avoiding large gaps.

I did think about using a Trigger instead, and then using that to find the existing Max value. Didn't seem clean. I also thought it would cause concurrency issues.

I'm happy to have a surrogate key here, but without Sequences I am wondering what the recommended route would be to actually generate the value for the surrogate at insert time.

Any advice appreciated.

Edit: Please note I am using the older "Web/Business" type of DB rather than the new tiers; I don't know if that will make a difference to any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your feedback has been marked as it was is because auto-increment by 1 becomes a very hard problem to solve at a database layer at scale.  If you "shard" your database (split it to cope with load) how would each shard know which number to increment to?  This should be extracted from the database and built into your application logic.

Without knowing the background requirement to having an incremental number it's hard to advise of the right solution.  Is it for uniqueness or for a sequence? If it's for a sequence does it really matter that it isn't by 1 each time as long as the number is (a) unique and (b) increases on each insert?  Could you make the setting of this sequence an offline process? That is - use insert date / time via a batch process to assign a sequence number?

If it's for uniqueness use a GUID or similar.

Comment: My feedback? Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: The background requirement is for incremental invoice numbers in an accounts package. Increasing by a few numbers is not a big problem, but by 1000 every couple of days is not going to be acceptable to my end user. Hence my use of a surrogate key rather than the identity field in the front end. At the moment I have been doing exactly as you say and using a scheduled task to assign a sequence number, but I thought there must be a better more "SQL" way to do it.

Comment: I meant your feedback on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: That is nothing to do with me, they are not comments from me on there.

Comment: Why can't you just have a table that stores the LastInvoiceNumber and get the next number from there? That's what I do.

Comment: @Craig - while that could work, you would likely, under load, end up with a deadlock if you were trying to read a number and increment it by one.  This might not be an issue if it simply generates a retry and you maybe skip one or two numbers.

Comment: Potentially there could be problems if you have a system that is generating thousand of invoices a minute, but is that realistic?